# forget login in org-jira

Tags: org-mode

I am using [org-jira](https://github.com/ahungry/org-jira), and generally am happy with it (read happier than using Jira).

However, when I am trying to login, but mistyped my username/password, every operation later fails, and I don't seem to have an other chance to login.

So my question is **how to get back to the org-jira login prompt again?**